# Custom modules disappeared after 2.2.9 upgrade

Tags: module, magento2.2, custom, upgrade

All custom modules have disappeared after upgrade to 2.2.9 from 2.1.9. When I run bin/magento setup:upgrade, last message is "Nothing to import." but the custom modules are not enabled and not added to the app/etc/config.php file.

Comment: Have you checked in setup_module table that there module's entry already exist or not?

Comment: Yes the custom modules already exist, do I have to remove them?

Comment: Yes you have to remove that entry and try to run setup:upgrade command

Comment: I removed a module and run setup:upgrade command, this module was not added to the config.php file and the setup_module table.

Comment: Strange. Have u checked any file missing for module like registration.php or modules.xml?

Comment: The modules.xml and registration.php files are well present for all the custom modules. These module were well recognized and perfectly work before magento upgrade.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95444/discussion-between-raj-and-mathieu).

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved, the app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php file was absent.